# Let $k, m, n$ be natural numbers. If $k$ divides $n$ and if $m$ divides $n$ then $km$ divides $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I prove this?  If we go for a direct proof and assume that $k\mid n$ and $m\mid n$ we get:

$ka = n$ where $a$ is an element of $\mathbb N$ and $mb = n$ where $b$ is an element of $\mathbb N$.

Hints / thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: This is false. Let $k=m=n=2$.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin Long proved, this is false. However, if you assume that $\gcd(k,m)=1$, then you have $km\mid n$ as desired. To prove this, you can use Bezout's identity: As $\gcd(k,m)=1$, we know that $\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z},\,xk+ym=1$